# Excel Add-Ins custom functions not loaded in Excel on-line

Tags: office-js, excel-addins

Add-Ins custom functions work fine on desktop, but throw a CORS error when loaded in on-line Excel:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://xl.celin.io/assets/functions.json. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 200.

Comment: What does your manifest.xml file look like?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi @BrianGonzalez here is a [link to the manifest](https://github.com/Herdubreid/xl-docs/blob/main/manifest.xml)

Comment: The manifest looks fine. How are you creating the add-in? When I created the add-in, all the distribution files are in the root directory. How did your functions.json get in your assets folder? The only file I have in my assets folder are some logos.

Comment: I just copied functions.json to the assets folder.  I don't think it matters where it is as long as the URL is correct in the manifest.  Where do you publish your add-ins?  I'm guessing the problem is with having the add-ins on a custom domain (non-Microsoft domain).

Comment: Once I make my updates to the add-in, I run `npm run build` to create the distribution folder. Using the distribution folder I publish to the root directory of my distributed add-in. I have a Powershell script that does all of this automatically. My add-in is published on Github Pages. If other functionality in your add-in is working then this probably isn't your issue however.

Comment: Ah I see that your manifest correctly references the assets folder. So as long as the necessary files are moved there it shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether CORS header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" is configured for the add-in's server. For example, in sample add-in created by `yo office`, there is the following field in `webpack.config.js`:

```js
devServer: {
      ...,
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      },
      ...
    },
```

Comment: That was it!  The "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header was missing from the Add-Ins host.  Thanks!